# How do i wrap woocomerce attribute in list?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, list, customization

I want to wrap a particular woocomerce attribute value in a list.

e.g. include is a attribute i want to wrap it value in a list.

i have attached a image for your reference

[image]

Comment: If you have a question about the inner workings of a third party plugin, you have a better chance of getting an answer at its author's forum, in this case: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global $product;  $attributes = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_attribute_name' );
```